# Jboss + mod_rewrite =?

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, jboss, mod-jk

I have 2 servers, Apache and Jboss. Using JKmount .war files are mounted and present a complex site.

eg:

```
JkMount /directory/* ajp13
Alias /directory /jboss/server/default/deploy/directory.war
<Directory  /jboss/server/default/deploy/directory.war>
  Order allow,deny
  allow from all
  Options -Indexes
</Directory>
<Directory  /jboss/server/default/deploy/directory.war/WEB-INF>
  deny from all
</Directory>
```

I would like to use mod_rewrite on the Apache side to alter the URLs returned by mod_jk.

eg:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^192.168.1.1$
RewriteRule /.* http://server.example/redirect.html [R=301,L]
```

Currently the above code only affects the images returned by Apache and not the pages returned by mod_jk.

Is this possible?
How is it done?

There is a similar question asked at [StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91038/how-to-rewrite-an-url-on-a-jboss-server?s=a2c5a782-c22f-4579-9d2b-28b8b0934dda) however given a choice if it is possible I would like to handle this internal to Apache and not alter the Jboss configuration.

The server is OpenSuse 11.1 and I suspect there maybe some module precedence order issues however I have not been able to confirm this.

Examples of URLs would be:

```
http://site.example/directory/index.jsp
http://site.example/foo/other.html
```

In this example the first URL is mounted in mod_jk using the directives listed in the config above and would NOT be re-written by mod_rewrite. The second URL is a normal directory in the Apache site and is rewritten correctly.

Thanks All

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a long search I have found the answer to this one.

The rewrite directive must be placed globally for the (virtual) host not in the  or in a .htaccess. Apache appears not to actually parse those files as the files served out of mod_jk are not part of that structure; which makes sense if you think about it. It will however apply mod_rewrite rules that apply to the entire host.

Answer (score 1):

sorry cant comment, Im new here ... can you give an example url which is returned from mod_jk.
Looks like the regular expression doesn`t fit to the page returned.

Try to redirect all to http://server.example/redirect.html:

```
RewriteRule .* http://server.example/redirect.html [R=301,L]
```

If this works, its the regular expression, which troubles you.

Let me explain a little bit.

you have an URI which looks like:
http://foo.bar.com/anything

Your regular expression `(/.*)` is now searching for a slash followed by something.
But in the Uri, there is  no / in "anything".

If you have an image:
e.g.

http://foo.bar.com/images/image.png than there is an / in images/image.png and the regular expression matches and does the redirect.

If you want to redirect somesite to another Server:

http://foo.bar.com/somesite -> http://bar.foo.com use

```
RewriteRule somesite.* http://server.example/redirect.html [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't a regex issue. I am bouncing every URL as that is my intention however URLs returned by mod_jk are not re-written; I suspect this may have something to do with the precedence of mod_rewrite vs mod_jk however I really don't have any evidence to back that up. Re-writes of image URLs are performed correctly and are in the same position as the index.jsp which is not re-written at all (but should be).

Comment: It could be a precendence issue. But you don´t give a concrete example of what you are trying to do. You say mod_jk generates an URL and it is not redirected. But if your regex is wrong, it would not be redirected at all, no matter if there is a precendence or not. So are you 100% sure it´s not the problem of your regular expression, or is it just a guess?

Comment: I am as certain as it is possible to be with these things is that it is not an issue with the regex; regardless of the expression used they do not affect URLs returned through mod_jk. Prior to posting I have tried a large number of regexs including your example. In all cases they affect URLs returned by apache but not those by mod_jk. For clarity I have added in example URLs.

Comment: Did you also tried the RewriteCondition thing? Maybe the precedence of the RewriteCondition is higher than the mod_jk thing.
But thats just a guess.

Comment: The problem is mod_jk isn't affected by anything, you can put a Deny from All in the root of a directory with a mod_jk submount and it will still return the mod_jk pages.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, can't comment, but in response to your answer Antitribu, you could also put the rewrite statements in a `<Location>` context.  There's a nice [section of the apache manual that describes when to use <File>, <Location>, .htaccess, etc](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/sections.html#file-and-web).